# iOS app store guideline 3.1.4 content codes

Tags: ios, applications, ios-appstore, apple-store

Lately I submitted an app to the App Store, but unfortunately, it has been rejected because based on them it's not in compliance with guideline 3.1.4 content code.

The app is basically messaging app like WhatsApp, but the only difference is that groups can be joined by ten chars code that the app generates.
I tried to explain to Apple that 3.1.4 is not the case and the codes are generated free and that is basically the same as links.
What do you think? What can I say to them?

> 3.1.4 Content Codes: Apps may not use their own mechanisms to unlock content or functionality, such as license keys, augmented reality markers, QR codes, etc. In limited circumstances, such as when features are dependent upon specific hardware to function, the app may unlock that functionality without using in-app purchase (e.g. an astronomy app that adds features when synced with a telescope). App features that work in combination with an approved physical product (such as a toy) on an optional basis may unlock functionality without using in-app purchase, provided that an in-app purchase option is available as well. You may not, however, require users to purchase unrelated products or engage in advertising or marketing activities to unlock app functionality.